# Inferring template argument type, template class versus template function

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have defined a deleter for set having pointer object , but when I have defined in the below manner it wasn't working and saying 
In function 'int main()': 41:43: error: missing template arguments before '(' token In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/set:
That was the line where I was using Deleter

```
template <typename T>
struct Deleter
{
  void operator () (T *ptr)
  {
     delete ptr;
  }
};
```

But when I changed the place of template declaration as shown below it started working .

```
struct Deleter1
{
  template <typename T>
  void operator () (T *ptr)
  {
     delete ptr;
  }
};
```

Can anybody explains what exactly the difference is . Because when we declare a class having template variable or even function having template parameter we declare template declaration before the class definition .

Comment: You don't use set in any of the shown code.  Show us a [mcve].

Comment: Reopened. This is not a duplicate of the earlier question; it's about the **difference** between the two code snippets.

Comment: You don't show how and where you use your custom deleter. The answer comparing your two code snippets will probably not satisfy you.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a function template the compiler can often tell from the way the function is called what the template argument must be. So in a call like this

```
Deleter1 d1;
int *ip = new int;
d1(ip);
```

the compiler infers that `T` is `int`.

For the corresponding code using the first one, you'd write

```
Deleter d;
int *ip = new int;
d(ip);
```

note that at the point of definition of `d` there is no way for the compiler to know that `d()` will be called with an `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody explains what exactly the difference is

The first is a class template. The instances of the template are classes that have a member function.

```
int* silly_int = new int;
float* silly_float = new float;
Deleter<int> d;    // Deleter<int> is a class
d(silly_int);      // it can delete int pointers using the member function
Deleter<float> d2; // Deleter<float> is another class
d2(silly_float);   // it can delete float pointers
```

The second is a class that has a member function template. The instances of the template are member functions.

```
Deleter1 d3;      // Deleter1 is a class
d3(silly_int);    // it too can delete int pointers 
d3(silly_float);  // and pointers of other types as well
                  // using different instance of the member function template
```

Answer (score 0):

With your first type, `Deleter`, you create objects which accept a fixed type.

```
// del_int only accepts int pointers
Deleter<int> del_int;
// del_string only accepts std::string pointers
Deleter<std::string> del_string;

int* ip = new int;
std::string* sp = new std::string;

del_int(ip);    // ok
del_string(sp); // ok
del_int(sp);    // error
del_string(ip)  // error
```

But with `Deleter1`, you can create a single object, and it will accept any pointer, because its member `operator()` is templated.

```
// del_any will accept any kind of pointer
Deleter1 del_any;

int* ip = new int;
std::string* sp = new std::string;

del_any(ip); // ok
del_any(sp); // ok
```

Answer (score 0):

The first has the template parameter on the struct and to create the struct the compiler needs to know what type it is creating the struct for. As we're using the default constructor which has no arguments the compiler cant deduce the type and you need to explicitly specify it, i.e.

```
Deleter<Foo>()
```

The compiler then creates a 'Foo Deleter' struct with an operator() function that only accepts an argument of type Foo*.

The second version defines a regular struct that has a templated function.
In this case the compiler will generate an operator() function for every type that the function is called with. It will deduce the type from the function argument.